How can I Screen Share into Ubuntu remotely after a fresh boot?
I usually use Ubuntu via Screen Share (RDP) in another building and sometimes I need to reboot.
But 1st thing after a reboot is a box asking to authorise the keychain/keyring which I can't type into remotely.
I do not wish to root/sudo the whole OS in order to get around this as others have suggested.
As another example, I also use my iMac remotely via Screen Share in a similar fashion. If I reboot the machine, I can still Screenshare into the login screen and type my password after a reboot. There is no need to disable any passwords or security features.
So how can I reboot a Screen Shared Ubuntu OS and get to the desktop again If I can't physically type things into the keyboard?

So the way to do this without creating massive security issues (which no Stack or LLMs suggested) is start with a fresh empty login keychain that only handles getting the desktop up and running.
This can have the blank password.
Then create a new keyring and make it the default. All other authentication credentials get stored here.
The Gnome desktop will now be logged in on boot.
Depending on the setup, the new keyring might shown up at login and ask to be unlocked, but because the login keyring is now unlocked, the other keyring can be authenticated via Remote Desktop like it can be done on a Mac.

you need to set a blank password for the keyring (yup - I know).
have a look at the documentation here:
blank pw needed

Yes blank password is the first answer that shows up... usually followed by DO NOT DO THIS for obvious reasons so this was never acceptable for me.
